# Swift - Read Data from Firebase (Realtime-Database)

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im completely new in Xcode Development.

I have created the following database in my Firebase:

```
{
  "Bicycle" : {
    "BMX" : {
      "image" : "bmx.png",
      "text" : "BMX ..."
    },
    "Dirt jumping" : {
      "image" : "dirtjumping.png",
      "text" : "Dirt jumping..."
    }
  },
  "Running" : {
    "Half-marathon" : {
      "image" : "halfmarathon.png",
      "text" : "Half-marathon ..."
    },
    "Marathon" : {
      "image" : "marathon.png",
      "text" : "Marathon ..."
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to show "Bicycle" and "Running" in the first TableViewController.

When I try the following code:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("sports").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    for case let rest as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(rest.children)
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2
<FTransformedEnumerator: 0x6000038b40a0>
<FTransformedEnumerator: 0x6000038b40a0>
```

Maybe you can give me a good tip.

Kind regards,
doomsweb

Comment: As a newbie you should to do some research. Have a look at Firebase documentation, They have provided the enough content for how to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Get `snapshot.value` as Dictionary and get the details from the dictionary

```
ref.child("sports").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let sports = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] { 
        for (title, details) in sports {
            print(title)//Bicycle
            print(details)//["BMX" : ["image" : "bmx.png", "text" : "BMX ..."], "Dirt jumping" : ["image" : "dirtjumping.png","text" : "Dirt jumping..."]]
        }
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, next step is to show Bicycle and Running in my TableViewController. In my first Version I used just a fixed Array. I append the title in a empty Array. Do I have to work with async here so that the array is not empty?

Comment: Hm i don't really understand struct.
I created a new Swift-File with

struct SportStruct {
    var sportsarray = [String]()
}

Is the first step correct or completely wrong?

Comment: @doomsweb Check [link1](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/structs-in-swift-for-newbies-bf64f3d40f68) [link2](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/15/structs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snapshot.valueInExportFormat()` to get data in dictionary format.